# install visual studio 2013 on D drive.

Tags: visual-studio

Last week, I bought dell venue pro 32gb with 32gb sd card.

I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 in sd card because of not enought space on C:\, But this wasn't easy.

I made my sd card non-removable disk.

I also tried Symbolic link between C:\ and D:\, But it also requires C drive's space.

Is there any other way to install Visual Studio 2013 on D drive without any space using on C:\?

Answer (score 3):

I found partial solution here:

https://aurir.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/installing-visual-studio-on-dell-venue-8-pro-tablets-microsd-card/

You basically create mount of D in C and install it on that mount. However VS still installs some bloat to C.

If you are interested in installation parameters for VS. They are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx

Answer (score 3):

According to my research, Visual studio will *always* require at least *some* space on the system drive:

> While Visual Studio 11 does allow you to install the majority of features to another drive, VS11 still requires space on the system drive for the following reasons:
>
> - Shared runtimes like the .NET Framework and Visual C/C++ which require installing into the system drive.
> - Packages shared with other products that have their own installation folders like SQL Server and Windows SDK
> - Components shared with other applications like Office or services like IIS
>     Windows Installer and package caches

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2012/03/07/why-visual-studio-11-requires-space-on-the-system-drive.aspx

There's some potential alternatives for reducing space on there as well, though again; it will still require some space on the system drive.

(Note: That guide is specifically talking about Visual Studio 11, instead of Visual Studio 2013; however, there's no indication that this has changed as of VS 2013; and given the reasons cited, e.g. being based on the vital components *themselves*, I see no reason to expect would have changed in VS 2013.)

There's also a UserVoice page you can vote for the idea here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2120283-allow-users-to-install-entirely-to-another-hard-dr (though again, there's the strong indication there that it's not likely to happen, at least any time soon.)