# How to force Visual Studio NOT to install components into C:\ (System Drive)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

During a Visual Studio instalation ***(2015 offline download)***, I specifically set the installaltion directory as **D:\V.Studio**, but still Visual Studio goes on to install most of the components into **C:\** !

How can I force the Visual Studio components to get installed into a drive **NOT C:\**?

Comment: someone already asked hope this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467031/install-visual-studio-2013-on-d-drive

Comment: you can use this tool to link the folder from C: to D: https://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Visual Studio components are always installed to the System drive including things like .NET, MSBuild, Windows 8.1 SDK, Windows 10 SDK, etc.

Comment: Can that be changed to a different drive?

Comment: In short, no. You can file a request at [VS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) but this has been a long-standing issue (going back to VS 2005 or earlier). The Windows 8.0 or later SDKs do not provide a method for installing to a drive other than C.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links can be created in the command line with a special command that was first introduced in Vista. It is called Mklink (described in more detail here) and here is how it works for a folder:

1. Before doing anything, make sure you have a backup of your system
2. Move (not copy) the desired folder (let’s call it ExistingName) by the usual methods to its new destination on the X:\ volume. Give it whatever name you choose. Let’s call it NewName but it can retain ExistingName if you wish.  At this point programs and Registry references may be broken. It is necessary to move the folder first since otherwise no symbolic link can be created on the C.\ drive
3. Next open a command prompt with elevated privileges. (This previous tip explains how.)
4. Enter the command mklink /d C:\ExistingName X:\NewName The switch /d indicates that we are linking folders (directories). No switch would be used if a file was being linked. If your folder name has spaces, you have to enclose the path name in quotes.
5. If a link is successfully made, the command line will show a message “symbolic link created for ExistingName <<===>> X:\NewName”.
6. Close the command prompt

That's all it takes. All of the previous Registry or other references to C:\ExistingName will continue to work. The command creates a small object on the C:\ drive that retains the previous folder name and behaves as if it has the contents of the folder that is really over on the X:\ drive.

It’s the magic of symbolic links.

Comment: Has anyone tested this with Visual Studio? Seems like a good option.